# How to merge text files with the same name from all sub directories. and merge data will be store according to date and time?

Tags: python

I am new in python, I am trying to merge same name files arranging data in new merged file according to date and time but I am not able to merge data according to date and time and also want to remove data duplication.
File names start with a digit, e.g., `89.txt`, `100.txt`, `2.txt`.
**Data format is like this in all sub-directory folder.**

```
 1. 30:01:2019:15:20:50:0.04,0.15,-5.05,81.25,35.47,-05.60,0.37,-1.61,0.22
 2. 20:01:2019:20:40:30:0.04,0.05,-1.04,71.25,55.37,-20.50,0.37,-5.71,0.24
```

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
file_paths = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.txt'):
            if f not in file_paths:
                file_paths[f] = []
            file_paths[f].append(root)
#def sort_key(line):
#return datetime.strptime(line.split(']')[0], '[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
for f, paths in file_paths.items():
    txt = []
    for p in paths:
        with open(os.path.join(p, f)) as f2:
            txt.append(f2.read())
    with open(f, 'w') as f3:
        f3.write(''.join(txt))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format you question in a readable way and be sure to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Mukesh, I have edited your post but I had to make some educated guesses wrt indentation of the last nested for loops, could you please verify that I haven't messed up everything? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi gboffi, I m trying to merge same file from multiple  sub-directory.and create same name file root folder.